# sonar h2 Initializing Hibernate

Tags: sonarqube, h2

Problem when run sonar with h2, why hibernate not init,so table could not be found:

```
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.0.1

10:27:11.403 INFO  - Load global referentials...

10:27:11.586 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 187 ms

10:27:11.591 INFO  - User cache: D:\Project\.sonar\cache

10:27:11.605 INFO  - Install plugins

10:27:11.976 INFO  - Install JDBC driver

10:27:11.987 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://172.27.18.11:9091/sonar

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Total time: 2.660s

Final Memory: 2M/15M

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution

ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar

ERROR: Caused by:
 Error querying database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PROPERTIES" not found; SQL statement:

select p.id as id, p.prop_key as "key", p.text_value as value, p.resource_id as resourceId, p.user_id as userId
    from properties p
    where p.prop_key=?
      AND p.resource_id is null*
```

Comment: I would try using an absolute path, for example `jdbc:h2:tcp://172.27.18.11:9091//data/db/sonar` (notice the double slashes)

Comment: Still  error: 

17:30:19.461 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://172.27.18.11:9091//opt/app/sonarqube-5.0.1/sonar

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE

ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution

ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar

ERROR: Caused by:

### Error querying database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PROPERTIES" not found; SQL statement:

select p.id as id, p.prop_key as "key", p.text_value as value, p.resource_id as resourceId, p.user_id as userId

    from properties p

    where p.prop_key=?